# Xcode margins strange behavior

Tags: ios, xcode

I have table view cell like this in a xib file:

[image: cell]

On iOS 8 it looks as I want, but on iOS 7 the image view on left side and view on the right side look like this:

[image: cell]

I know about iOS 8 margins and I have made constraints without the "Constraint to margins" option.

How can I make iOS 7 table view cell similar to iOS 8?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show all the constraints. Here is an excellent [auto-layout tableview sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/4140018) 
which will walk you through the iOS **Size Classes** or just refer this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/).